# Ignore IllegalTokenText warning in Checkstyle 3.0 version

Tags: checkstyle

I'm using checkstyle 3.0 version and getting following error:

> Consider using special escape sequence instead of octal value or
>   Unicode escaped value. [IllegalTokenText]

I want to ignore/suppress this warning(`IllegalTokenText`). I have tried using `supressionCommentFilter` but I think it works for checkstyle release 3.2 and above.

Please guide me how can I ignore/suppress checkstyle warnings in 3.0 version.

Cheers :)

Comment: Are you sure about the version being 3.0? That would be almost 15 years old ...

Comment: @oOXAam Why can't you upgrade to a newer version of checkstyle?

Comment: @ThomasJensen   Actually it's a enterprise application of some client and they don't want to upgrade it. That's why, I'm stuck.

Comment: @oOXAam IllegalTokenText was added in Checkstyle 3.2 . Please verify what version you are working with. If it is 3.2, then you can atleast use SuppressionFilter.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have been saying 3.0 is very very old, and no filters were around back then.

Since your client doesn't want to upgrade Checkstyle, your only options are:

1) Remove IllegalTokenText (or set its severity to ignore) in your configuration

2) Convince them to upgrade. Many improvements, bug fixes, and new checks have been added since then all of which they are missing out on.

3)

I am assuming (since I am not that familiar with the old code) that Checkstyle is still expandable back in that day like it is now. You could try to create a custom listener to act like a filter in the old Checkstyle to suppress the violation you want to ignore. 3.0 didn't have filter support back then, and you can't add it in. First make sure you can add a listener through the configuration, otherwise, this may not even be an option.

Checkstyle 3.0 source: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/tree/release3_0
How to write a listener: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writinglisteners.html (Note this is the newer version documentation)

4)

Similar to the writting a custom listener, write a custom IllegalTokenText with suppression support.

How to write a check: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html (Note this is the newer version documentation)

I don't see any other options then these.